# How to put Google Analytics api response in a sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I want to import Google Analytics remarketing Audiences into a spreadsheet. I get the response from Google Analytics Management API, but I cannot get my head around on how to parse this and get it into a spreadsheet.

```js
    function getlists() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var acc = XXX;
      var prop = "UA-XXX-1";
      var lists = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.list(acc,prop)
      Logger.log(lists.items)
    }
```

The response is as follows:

> {kind=analytics#remarketingAudience, created=2016-07-04T16:40:12.601Z, description=Transakcje > 0, webPropertyId=UA-XXX-1, audienceDefinition={includeConditions={kind=analytics#includeConditions, segment=sessions::condition::ga:transactions>0, membershipDurationDays=30, isSmartList=false}}, accountId=XXX, linkedViews=[XXX], name=Google shopping kupili, id=XXX, audienceType=SIMPLE, updated=2016-07-04T16:40:49.145Z, internalWebPropertyId=XXX, linkedAdAccounts=[{remarketingAudienceId=XXX, eligibleForSearch=true, accountId=XXX, linkedAccountId=DELETED, kind=analytics#linkedForeignAccount, id=XXX, type=ADWORDS_LINKS, internalWebPropertyId=XXX, webPropertyId=UA-XXX-1, status=CLOSED}]}

I would like to put this response into a spreadsheet where it would be outlined:

```
Kind | Created | Description | etc.

A | B | C | D
```

I cannot wrap my head around, how to achieve this.

Comment: Use proper tags for your question to reach the right audience. You can read the usage guideline of each tag, when you click on it

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
  var items = lists.items;
  var temp = [];
    temp.push(["id","name","kind","IncludeKind","IncludeIsSmart","IncludeSegment","membershipDurationDays"]);

  for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    temp.push([items[i].id,items[i].name,items[i].kind,items[i].audienceDefinition.includeConditions.kind,items[i].audienceDefinition.includeConditions.isSmartList,items[i].audienceDefinition.includeConditions.segment,items[i].audienceDefinition.includeConditions.membershipDurationDays]);
  }

  ss.getRange(1, 1, temp.length, 7).setValues(temp);
`
```